# Why does it do nothing after these git commands?

Tags: git, github

I'm newbie with git.

My fork:
[Fork @ https://github.com/bigopon/binding](https://github.com/bigopon/binding)

Master repo: [Aurelia @ https://github.com/aurelia/binding](https://github.com/aurelia/binding)

My commands (executed in same order):

```
git clone https://github.com/bigopon/binding.git
cd binding
git remote add upstream https://github.com/aurelia/binding.git
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

I got a conflict, after resolving it:

```
git add *
git commit -m "Resolved"
```

I got these messages:

> You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '36215e6'.
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean

And

```
git push origin master
```

does nothing

**Update**: following is what happened:

```
C:\Users\Bigo\Desktop\aurelia-forks>git clone 
https://github.com/bigopon/binding.git
Cloning into 'binding'...
remote: Counting objects: 4560, done.
remote: Total 4560 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 4560R
Receiving objects: 100% (4560/4560), 4.52 MiB | 939.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3143/3143), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

C:\Users\Bigo\Desktop\aurelia-forks>cd binding

C:\Users\Bigo\Desktop\aurelia-forks\binding>git remote add upstream https://github.com/aurelia/binding.git

C:\Users\Bigo\Desktop\aurelia-forks\binding>git fetch upstream
remote: Counting objects: 99, done.
remote: Total 99 (delta 60), reused 60 (delta 60), pack-reused 39
Unpacking objects: 100% (99/99), done.
From https://github.com/aurelia/binding
 * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master
 * [new tag]         1.2.1      -> 1.2.1
 * [new tag]         1.1.1      -> 1.1.1
 * [new tag]         1.2.0      -> 1.2.0

C:\Users\Bigo\Desktop\aurelia-forks\binding>git rebase upstream/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Add self binding behavior section
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       doc/article/en-US/binding-binding-behaviors.md
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging doc/article/en-US/binding-binding-behaviors.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in doc/article/en-US/binding-binding-behaviors.md
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Add self binding behavior section
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   C:/Users/Bigo/Desktop/aurelia-forks/binding/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".


C:\Users\Bigo\Desktop\aurelia-forks\binding>
```

What should I do here ? As suggested by @merlin2011 in his answer, i shouldn't commit during rebase

Comment: why did you `rebase` here? I fail to see the need for it..

Comment: Please edit the question to include what exactly you were expecting to happen when the confusion arose.

Comment: @ashmaroli I've updated the question with all output

Comment: Also, if you are rebasing your branch on top of the origin repository, this amounts to rewriting the public history of your github fork, so you would have to `git push -f origin master` to make this work, since the master has a different history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is simply because of the `rebase` command which was unnecessary.
`rebase` rewrites the git index history of the current branch which is not advised on the `master` branch.

You should simply `pull` to sync changes to `master`.

```
git remote add upstream [...]
git pull upstream master
```

Since you haven't started working on the branch yet, I suggest you to reset your branch:

```
git reset --hard upstream/master --
git push origin master
```

Comment: Hi, what do I do when I get this one ?
![result](http://image.prntscr.com/image/59d0089c89b94101b8104fac9aab8b10.png)
I did pull `upstream master` before push `origin master`

Comment: Following your suggestion (with reset --hard before pull), I now have my repo up to date, however, the history of old commits (that got merged into master repo) is still there. Can you help tell me what i should do to get rid of it ? as it says my branch is now 3 commit aheads of master repo

Comment: `git reset --hard` to that last `<COMMIT>` upstream.. e.g. `git reset --hard 36215e6` and then force update remote branch with `--force` switch: `git push origin master --force`

Comment: Contributing to OSS without git knowledge is quite harsh sometimes. Thanks for your help. Just got it even with master now. One last question please: Did I lose all history when doing `push --force` ?

Comment: You're welcome. Git is very easy to learn. Another thing to keep in mind with OSS, always keep your `master` branch pristine. Create a new branch off `master` and work on that branch.

Answer (score 2):

After resolving a conflict during `git rebase`, the next steps are to add and then continue the rebase. You **should not** be using `git commit` during a rebase. Instead, you should do the following steps after fixing conflicts.

```
# First fix conflicts
git add ConflictedFile1 ConflictedFile2
git rebase --continue
```

Also, if you are rebasing your branch on top of the origin repository, this amounts to rewriting the public history of your github fork, so you would have to `git push -f origin master` to make this work, since the master has a different history.

Comment: Yes I did, and the message in the question is what I got

Comment: @bigopon, Yes you did what?

Comment: I meant I did add the file, then run the commit command with a message "Resolved"

Comment: I've updated question with all output until commit step, @merlin2011

Comment: @bigopon, As I said in the answer, use `git rebase --continue` after resolving conflicts and adding resolved files. DO NOT COMMIT.